# Tastypie Nested Resource URIs

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I'm creating an API where I would like to `POST` and `GET` the children objects from the parent object. For example:

- `GET challenge/1/solutions`  = `[Listof Solutions] filtered with challenge_id=1`
- `GET challenge/1/solution/1` = `Solution with id=1 filtered with challenge_id=1`
- `POST challenge/1/solution`  = `Add to Solution with challenge_id=1`

The `solution` URLs only return user's submitted solutions. The URLs above are used to access the list of solutions for each challenge.

I need this solution to apply to multiple children objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [delicious-cake](https://github.com/dasickis/delicious-cake) instead